# How to insert into firebird tables with constraint loops?

Tags: firebird

I have tables with contain loops in firebird. I haven't found a good way to insert data where **Table A** has a FK to **Table B** and **Table B** has a FK to **Table A**.

This is not an unusual database problem, but I cannot get firebird to let me insert the rows. Here is what I believe:

1. firebird has flags for deferred constraint check, but it appear
   they are not implemented as features (true?).
2. Firebird 3.0 Docs don't seem to mention deferred constraint
   checking as a feature addition (is it going to be in there?)
3. From what I can tell, you can't insert two rows into two tables
   within a single transaction to get around the problem. (is this
   true?)
4. Is the only option to drop all constraints during an insert? (not so awesome)

Comment: Firebird does not have deferred triggers. The metadata tables have been derived from a predecessor of Interbase that was written at - I believe- DEC, where two competing database products used the same metadata structure and API. Either the other system did have deferred triggers, or this was something that was planned but never implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to use non required fields, insert the 2 lines without FK values, and then update them.

If you want to make it in a single statement, it must be possible using a stored procedure or a "execute block"

Best regards